# SignalR Client accept self signed certificates

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying out SignalR core and while using Signal R .NET Client and trying to a connect to a server with https i get

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according
>   to the validation procedure.

The error is self explanatory but how do i get around this ?
I do want to accept self signed certs.

Searching over internet gave no conclusive answer and approaches as  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback no longer work and i suppose that is logical as they are not used in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: What is hosting the main app? Is this OWIN/self-hosted, or are you running through IIS?

Comment: Its self hosted with Kestrel.